# SQL validate previous value into a select

Tags: sql, select

Do you know if there is way to validate a previous record in a SQL query? I have the following information:

[image]

I would like to see the information as follows:

[image]

This is the query:

```
Select 
T1.Company, T1.Calc_CurDueDate, T1.InvoiceNum, t2.PackNum, T1.Calc_CustID,
0 As Calc_AgeInvAmt1,
CASE 
    WHEN T3.InvoiceAmt = T3.InvoiceBal THEN (SUM(T2.ExtPrice)-SUM(T2.DocDiscount)) 
    ELSE 36600 END as Calc_AgeInvAmt2, 
0 as Calc_AgeInvAmt3, 
0 as Calc_AgeInvAmt4, 
0 as Calc_AgeInvAmt5, 
0 as Calc_AgeInvAmt6
FROM ARDtls_23b33e365b2d46cc9552a2ee324d2cb1 T1
INNER JOIN InvcDtl_23b33e365b2d46cc9552a2ee324d2cb1 T2 
ON T2.Company = T2.Company AND T1.InvoiceNum = T2.InvoiceNum
INNER joIN InvcHead_23B33E365B2D46CC9552A2EE324D2CB1 T3 
ON T1.Company = T3.Company AND T1.InvoiceNum = T3.InvoiceNum
Group BY T1.Company, T1.Calc_CurDueDate, T1.InvoiceNum, t2.PackNum, T1.Calc_CustID, T3.InvoiceAmt, T3.InvoiceBal
HAVING T1.Calc_CurDueDate >= @MinAgeDate AND T1.Calc_CurDueDate < @AgeDate
```

Any idea would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question you need to get the difference between the current row and the previous row for the column Calc_AgeInvAmt2 when ordered by PackNum. Then you can use this:

```
With q as (... put your query here ...)
select InvoiceNum, PackNum, CalcCustID, Calc_AgeInvAmt1, Calc_AgeInvAmt2 - coalesce(lag(Calc_AgeInvAmt2) over (order by PackNum),0) as Calc_AgeInvAmt2 from q;
```